# HTML to HTML5 replace deprecated tags without loosing style properities

Tags: ruby, html, rubygems

I have been working in document conversation.
Is there any ruby gem or script to replace html deprecated tags without loosing styles.

**example:**

```
<font color= "#000000 "> something </font>
```

to

```
<span style = "color: #000000;"> something </span>
```

Comment: the clean way to tackle your problem would be processing the result of a html(4) parser replacing pertinent nodes and their attributes in the dom tree. be very wary of lexical pattern matching schemes. [this list](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing) tabulates some candidates. can't give you more concrete advice, however.

Comment: hi @collapsar thanks for your quick response. I have tried nokogiri and html-tidy. I find no method to manage these direct conversion in nokogiri. at this point of time I am not ready to parse elements and write conversion on my own. Instead I am looking for a ready alternative.

Comment: Why are you doing such conversions? It is a lot of work, with many pitfalls, you *will* make mistakes when working with any large piece of code, and the net gain is negative: the page will not work the intended way when CSS is disabled. Creating new documents is a different matter, but cleaning up legacy markup is mostly pointless.

Comment: Hi Korpela, Actually I was working on a plugin which takes doc and docx files and converts them to .html.
I have managed to convert them using openoffice libraries. but those converted files have old deprecated html tags. like <font> tag for instance.
but i want to totally replace them using span or something else. I have gone through many html cleaners online but none of them is in ruby. example: [using tidy](http://infohound.net/tidy/)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution after long research it is [Tidy](http://w3c.github.io/tidy-html5/).

It has html5 support. and has commandline tool and shared library as-well. which works pretty decent.

here is a  simple command which will convert our outdated html to html5.

```
tidy -c -m --indent true --doctype html5 sample.html
```